# Appending copyright notice to top of file during TFS check-in

Tags: tfs

A requirement for all of our code files is to include a copyright notice at the top of each file. Since there's no way I'm going to remember to do this, is there a way I can tap into TFS to do this for me?

I'd like a flow like this:

1. On check-in, get a list of files to be checked in.
2. For each file, check the file extension to determine the file type.
3. Append a comment as the first line of each file using the file extension to determine comment format.

What's the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Why not do this as a post build step instead of pre-checkin? That way you would have the additional piece of mind that nothing else was messed up in the file.

Comment: @allen also, it concerns me a bit to add something like this that could extend build time. It seems checking/adding to each file each time would be an expensive operation.

Comment: @MikeCole: you're going to check and add to each file at some point; TFS might be configured to only allow a checkin after a successful build... But I'd suggest this might be best done as a custom code analysis rule (in StyleCop or similar) so you can be warned of your transgressions.

Answer (score 1):

@Mike I am listing down the ways in which you could achieve this in increasing order of complexity

1. Add the copyright notice to the default file template. This way all new files will have this header by default.
2. Use a VS macro to add in the copyright - can find these online
3. Add the copyright during a pre build event - sample script below
4. If you have a gated checkin then modify the build template to add the copyright once the shelveset is queued for checkin - you can again use the script or convert it to c# code

You can avoid build time overheads by verifying if the action is needed or not

- Check if any files are being added using 'tf status'
- if there is an 'add' check if a copyright exists, if no, add in the header

Sample .ps1 script I use for a blanket addition in new .cs source code files.

```
$header = "// Copyright (c) My Corp. All rights reserved.`r`n"

function Write-Header ($file)
{
    $content = Get-Content $file

    $containsWord = $content | %{$_ -match "Copyright"}

    if($containsWord -match $true)
    {
        return
    }

    tf edit $file 

    $filename = Split-Path -Leaf $file

    Set-Content $file $header

    Add-Content $file $content
}

// you can modify this condition to apply this logic to new files only
Get-ChildItem "E:\src" -Recurse | ? { $_.Extension -match "[a-zA-Z]*\.cs$" } | % `
{
    Write-Header $_.PSPath.Split(":", 3)[2]
}
```

Comment: My only comment RE the post-build approach is that it means your build is immediately stale: you've changed your code from that which was built. Obviously you're only adding comments, but the purist in me would still want to know that the green build I just ran matches the code I have on disk...

Comment: So how do I execute the script in scenario 3? I copied and pasted into Post-build event command line in VS and it failed.

Comment: @Dan. I agree and that was on my mind when I replied in the comments but still typed in post instead of pre. Edited my ans :s/post/pre/g